# Building an executable jar with maven depencies and external jars

Tags: java, maven

I have an application where Im using maven dependecies and Im also using an external jar of a project which is located in my computer, the project is added to the application manually. The problem is whenever I export the project with maven, It only exports all maven dependencies, not the externatl jar that I have included manually. Is there anyway that I can export it?

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            ${project.build.directory}/libs
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>
                            com.cristianruizblog.loginSecurity.LoginSecurityTutorialApplication
                        </mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks for reading. If anyone can help I would be so happy!

Comment: Installl the jar in your maven repo, add it as a dependency. Don't mess around with things like this as this will break on a build server and others computers. Manage it as a proper dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @M. Deunum, try to get your external jar into a Maven repository to avoid enable any machine to build your jar. If this is no option, you can use the Maven [system dependency scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) to include the jar. Note that this is only a temporary solution as this scope has been marked as depricated.